# how to clean stack from removed pages?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

Now I'm developing an app that adds a web page and then I get the rss feeds of this page. In other activity then I open main pages list then i delete the page i just get its feeds .. after removing it if i press back button i find the feeds activity of this page !!

How can i delete this feeds activity from stack if i removed its page ??

this my code to start activity for feeds

```
map = pagesList.get(position);    
Intent intent = new Intent(PagesActivity.this, FeedsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fPageid", map.get(KEY_FID));
intent.putExtra("fPagename", map.get(KEY_NAME));
intent.putExtra("fPageimg", map.get(KEY_PICTURE));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: why you not use finish anfter starting activity  startActivity(intent); finish();

Comment: look at my comment in patrik answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use finish() after calling your Intent. See below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PagesActivity.this, FeedsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fPageid", map.get(KEY_FID));
intent.putExtra("fPagename", map.get(KEY_NAME));
intent.putExtra("fPageimg", map.get(KEY_PICTURE));
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Do above things at each and every Activity after its call. So previous one will be finished everytime or do it as per your need.

Comment: but i don't want to delete it if the page isn't deleted .. i mean if return back to feeds activity and i didn't remove its page then i want to find it

Comment: do finish() as per you need. Means if you want previous page then dont finish it. or if you have conditional coding then put condition there and then do finish().

Comment: but i need it sometimes and other times i want to delete it if i remove its page .. the question now how can i add condition and where to check if page is deleted

Comment: When you do your page delete at that time make one boolean variable true. Put that variable in SharedPreference or declare it static. Check in other activity that if that variable is true or false.

Comment: thank you pal .. i will try it .. i put another question but nobody answer it .. could you help me ??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172835/the-removed-alarms-come-back-one-after-the-other-when-i-reset-it

Comment: ya but please accept and upvote this answer. So other people can find useful.